# Is there an easy way in PostgreSQL to escape newlines, carriage returns, and tabs?

Tags: postgresql, functions, psql, string

Let's say I want to escape these to see a similar string

```
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES
  (E'\r\n\t FOO BAR \t\n\r')
) AS t(str);
```

How do I get the c-style escapes, `\r\n\t FOO BAR \t\n\r` back out?

```
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES
  (E'foo\nfoo',E'\n\tBAR\t','baz'),
  (E'quz','qaz','quz')
) AS t(x,y,z); 
  x  |        y         |  z  
-----+------------------+-----
 foo+|                 +| baz
 foo |         BAR      | 
 quz | qaz              | quz
(2 rows)
```

Want instead..

```
  x       |        y         |  z  
----------+------------------+-----
 foo\nfoo | \n\tBAR          | baz
 quz      | qaz              | quz
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use string escape syntax and `replace(string,substring,replacement)` function like below.

Please note it's heavily dependent on `standard_conforming_strings` setting. Should be `on`. You can find details [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html), [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html).

```
postgres=# \d t
     Table "public.t"
 Column | Type | Modifiers 
--------+------+-----------
 s      | text | 

postgres=# SELECT s, md5( s ), replace( replace( replace( s, E'\n', '\n' ), E'\t', '\t' ), E'\r', '\r' ) FROM t;
    s     |               md5                |  replace   
----------+----------------------------------+------------
 newline:+| 75c093ed14f1239a3510006326a1a260 | newline:\n
          |                                  | 
 tab:     | 355393c5cab9aa324c6ec90682b13d7e | tab:\t
 cr:\r    | 094911687582e40cfeb6217f8c760543 | cr:\r
(3 rows)
```

Comment: you should do `replace( s,e'\\',e'\\\\')` at the inner level to avoid ambiguous output

Answer (score 2):

postgresql is not doing this. you are looking at the data as represented to you by psql.

but if you want to see bytes, convert the data to bytes, and look at that:

```
jasen=# set bytea_output to escape;
jasen=# SELECT 
     convert_to(x,'utf8') as x_bytes, 
     convert_to(y,'utf8') as y_bytes, 
     convert_to(z,'utf8') as z_bytes
FROM ( VALUES
  (E'foo\nfoo',E'\n\tBAR\t','baz'),
  (E'quz','qaz','quz')
) AS t(x,y,z); 
  x_bytes   |     y_bytes     | z_bytes 
------------+-----------------+---------
 foo\012foo | \012\011BAR\011 | baz
 quz        | qaz             | quz
```